# ngCart only correctly works in Ionic app with syntax error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, shopping-cart

Currently I am developing a mobile app in Ionic for a local coffee roaster. Instead of building a cart from scratch I decided to integrate ngCart as a quick option that works with angular. After injecting the dependency into my app.js some individual components worked just fine, but the shopping cart summary and [cart.html](https://github.com/snapjay/ngCart/blob/master/template/ngCart/cart.html) did not work. I am not very familiar with Jasmine, but searching my project I found a function I wanted in [ngCart_test.html](https://github.com/snapjay/ngCart/blob/master/src/ngCart_test.js). So I copied the code from there into my CartController.js and that's when things get weird.

When I copied the code over it had an extra "})" which throws a syntax error, but everything works how it should. When I fix the syntax error it says, "describe not defined." I have tried unsuccessfully to fix the describe error but I am more curious as to why the syntax error makes ngCart work properly. I am guessing the syntax error breaks the js and causes the ngCart to load in the proper order, but I haven't been able to figure it out. I can send screenshots or additional info as needed.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you post your app code?

Comment: Which part? the controller?

Comment: Are you sure your app setup is correct? Your injections/modules etc. Otherwise at least your html and controller code.

Comment: Yeah I am sure I the app is set up correctly with injections and modules. I couldn't figure out it out, so I scrapped the ngCart idea and moved on. Really appreciate the help though @LJ.Wizard!